# Instance member 'reload' can't be accessed using static access

Tags: android, flutter, webview, refresh, reload

I'm working on aflutter project and i'm trying to reload my webview using this but they give me this error : `Instance member 'reload' can't be accessed using static access`
this is my code

```
bool connectionStatus = true;
Future check() async {
  Timer.periodic(new Duration(seconds: 10), (time) async {
    if (connectionStatus == false) WebViewController.reload();
    try {
      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
      if (result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
        connectionStatus = true;
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      connectionStatus = false;
    } });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `reload()` method for you *instance* of the `WebViewController` since it is not a static method.

So you must have created an instance of `WebViewController` somewhere. You need to save a reference, like

```
final _controller = WebViewController();
```

Then, in your `check()` method, use

```
_controller.reload();
```